# iOS app crash connected with iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, ios5, nsfetchedresultscontroller, icloud

My app uses just one `managedObjectContext` and is set up to sync coredata changes with iCloud, and I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch data for my `UITableView`. The problem occurs when I try to edit (reorder) the table cells.

Imagine this scenario:

I execute `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`
I hold down my finger on a row, and start to move it around the `tableView` (reorder).  In the meantime I delete a row in the mac app, and save the changes.

iOS app gets to know about the new changes and my `fetchedResultsController` tries to call `[tableView beginUpdates]` ... and remove the row from the `tableView` while it's being edited.

I don't know if it should work this way, but it crashes.

How would you try to solve this?

Log:

```
***[3758:707] asynchronously added persistent store!
***[3758:707] numberOfRowsInSection:3
***[3758:707] numberOfRowsInSection:2
***[3758:707] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1046
***[3758:707] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
***[3758:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

The first two logs are in the - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section method and log what i'm returning. I found out that the first time I returned 3, and the second time it was 2!

EDIT: And now im thinking ... should it work this way, or I have to find another way to make it ? What should happen when you're dragging a cell, and call [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:]; ?

Comment: It crashes, you say? Funny, you haven't pasted any information relating to the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your crash says that you started a `-beginUpdates` block, deleted a row, and then called `-endUpdates`, but when the tableview asked its data source for the number of rows in that section, it was handed back `3` when it expected `2`. It sounds like you're not updating your data source properly.

Comment: all the data fot the tableView are grabbed from fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects so they should be updated ... and as I already wrote ... numberOfRowsInSection: is called 2 times. The first time I return 3, and the second time I return 2.

Comment: @Kukosk: You're not returning 2. The exception very explicitly states that the number of rows in section 0 is `3` after the update, when it should be `2`.

Comment: but yes I do, and I'm sure I do because I put the NSLog(); to the numberOfRowsInSection: method ... and it gets called 2 times ... i am 100% sure I log what i return ...

Answer (score 0):

Even with logging it, something is happening.   I mean, it's breaking so it's obviously not working correctly right?
Some ideas:

1. Perhaps the method you are using to return the numberOfRowsInSection
   is set up improperly.
2. Perhaps cellForRowAtIndexPath is mistakenly looking at the wrong list.
3. You could be deleting and refreshing the display in a for loop.

Your error explicitly states that it's trying to find item at index 2.. at some point.  Why it's looking there is anyones guess without the source code.  I had some issues with these things and it was always my fault in the end.  A labor intensive but pretty foolproof way to figure this out is to put a shit-load of NSLog statements so you can trace what get's called when.  I'd guess that you are deleting the the object from the array at the incorrect time.  And very easy mistake to make.